# The use of superlative as in “the poorest half”

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

I saw the phrase "poorest half of the population." Is superlative always used with "half"? Is "poorer half" okay? Do you also say the "richest half"?

Comment: I think you mean "superlative", although "supremetive" has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Certainly you say "poorest" when there are three or more options: the poorest quarter of the population.  But with "half" you could say "poorer" instead.  But "poorest" still could be used.

Comment: I suppose it is grammatical and it does makes sense though a bit complicated for readers in general English. The superlative comes from the statistical aspect: counting upward from the **poorest** until you reach the middle, that is, the lower half of the population -- a rather involved expression that. Also, it is a specific case of "poorest xth" or "poorest n per cent" where x/n just happen to be  2 and 50.

Comment: 'The poorest half' only makes sense as an abbreviated form of 'that half of the population made up of the poorest people' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You would use 'poorest half' where you are looking to emphasise poverty, whereas you would use 'poorer half' where you are merely looking to indicate which half of a 50/50 split your are referring too. It is a subtle difference, but subtlety is what makes a language.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the comparative is traditionally preferred if you're only comparing two things, which is always the case with halves. So I would use *the poorer half*, at least in formal or literary English. *The poorest half*, however, is probably also used, and it will probably be immediately clear to readers what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: "probably be immediately clear": One could say much and be understood without necessarily being grammatical, which is what we do most of the time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

They both sound quite natural to me. It looks like "poorer "half" was much more common in the early 20th century, but both forms seem to appear: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poorer%20half%2Cpoorest%20half%2Cricher%20half%2Crichest%20half&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoorer%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoorest%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cricher%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crichest%20half%3B%2Cc0).